# php code to send sms without the manual entry of mobilenumber and message inside the code

Tags: php, html, api

```
<?php
//Please Enter Your Details
$user="user_name"; //your username
$password="your_password"; //your password
$mobilenumbers="0123456789"; //enter Mobile numbers comma seperated
$message = "Demo sms"; //enter Your Message 
$senderid="DEMO"; //Your senderid
$messagetype="N"; //Type Of Your Message 
$url="http://sms.mavyah.com/WebserviceSMS.aspx";
//domain name: Domain name Replace With Your Domain  
$message = urlencode($message);
$ch = curl_init(); 
if (!$ch){die("Couldn't initialize a cURL handle");}
$ret = curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);          
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 

"User=$user&passwd=$password&mobilenumber=$mobilenumbers&message=$
message&sid=$s
enderid&mtype=$messagetype");
$ret = curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);


//If you are behind proxy then please uncomment below line and provide your 
proxy ip with port.
// $ret = curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, "PROXY IP ADDRESS:PORT");

$curlresponse = curl_exec($ch); // execute
if(curl_errno($ch))
echo 'curl error : '. curl_error($ch);

if (empty($ret)) {
// some kind of an error happened
die(curl_error($ch));
curl_close($ch); // close cURL handler
} else {
$info = curl_getinfo($ch);
curl_close($ch); // close cURL handler
//echo "<br>";
echo $curlresponse;    //echo "Message Sent Succesfully" ;

}
?>
```

I have written PHP code for sending an SMS message. This code uses the SMs country API. In that code, as seen above, we have to include `$mobilenumbers` which tells to whom this message should be sent. But I need the changes for how to send the message to the recipient without mentioning the number in the code. i.e., when the HTMl form is filled with the receipient and message those fields should be taken as the input for `$mobilenumber` and `$message` in the code. We should not enter the number and message manually inside the code.

Comment: You username, password and phone number is showing in the post.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are getting the values from a form of some sort, like this:

```
<form name="form" action="" method="post">
  <input type="text" name="mobilenumbers" id="mobilenumbers" value="Mobile number">
  <input type="text" name="message" id="message" value="Message">
</form>
```

Then you just need to fetch the values from the form into you PHP code:

```
function sendSms($mobilenumbers, $message) {

  // Validation
  if ( ! is_numeric($mobilenumbers) ) {
    return;
  }
  $message = urlencode($message);

  $user="your_username"; //your username
  $password="your_password"; //your password
  $senderid="DEMO"; //Your senderid
  $messagetype="N"; //Type Of Your Message
  $url="http://sms.mavyah.com/WebserviceSMS.aspx";
  //domain name: Domain name Replace With Your Domain
  $ch = curl_init();
  if (!$ch){die("Couldn't initialize a cURL handle");}
  $ret = curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
  curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
  curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,

  "User=$user&passwd=$password&mobilenumber=$mobilenumbers&message=$
  message&sid=$s
  enderid&mtype=$messagetype");
  $ret = curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

  // If you are behind proxy then please uncomment below line and provide your
  // proxy ip with port.
  // $ret = curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, "PROXY IP ADDRESS:PORT");

  $curlresponse = curl_exec($ch); // execute
  if(curl_errno($ch))
  echo 'curl error : '. curl_error($ch);

  if (empty($ret)) {
  // some kind of an error happened
  die(curl_error($ch));
  curl_close($ch); // close cURL handler
  } else {
  $info = curl_getinfo($ch);
  curl_close($ch); // close cURL handler
  //echo "<br>";
  echo $curlresponse;    //echo "Message Sent Succesfully" ;

  }
}

// Call the function with the values provided by the form
sendSms($_POST('mobilenumbers'), $_POST('message'));
```

Wrap the code that never should change in a function and call that function with the values from the form. You should validate all user data, I have added a simple check for the phone number, is the value isn't a number then the function will fail silently.

Comment: Hello sir i tried the above code that you have posted. Not getting the output.